# queries with sub arrays mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, hierarchical-data

So I am creating this cms,

It uses mainpages and subpages (to an infinite level)

Usually I did (keep in mind, it's an example):

```
function getPages($parent_id = 0)
{
    $data = mysql("select * from pages WHERE parent_id=$parent_id");
    if($data)
    {
        for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++)
        {
            $data[$i]['subpages'] = getPages($data[$i]['id'];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Now I want to do something like this in one query, where I will select all subpages from a page to an infinite level and I want it to return as sub arrays, and not overwrite the main data (because of column names)

Table name is the same (pages) for either main pages and it's own subpages.

structure:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`follow` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`sub_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`page_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`content` text NOT NULL,
`seo_tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Added structure of table

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
  // Filling $data for the example. You can replace following lines by 
  // $data = mysql("select * from pages");

  $data = array(
            array("id" => 1, "name" => "a", "parent_id" => 0 ),
            array("id" => 2, "name" => "b", "parent_id" => 1 ),
            array("id" => 3, "name" => "c", "parent_id" => 2 ),
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "d1", "parent_id" => 3 ),
            array("id" => 5, "name" => "d2", "parent_id" => 3 )
          );

  function getPages($parent_id = 0)
  {
      global $data;
      $result = array();
      $resultSize = 0;
      if($data)
      {
          $countData = count($data);
          for($i=0; $i < $countData; $i++)
          {
              if ($data[$i]["parent_id"] == $parent_id) {
                $result[$resultSize] = $data[$i];
                $subpage = getPages($data[$i]["id"]);
                if (!empty($subpage)) {
                  $result[$resultSize]["subpages"] = $subpage;
                }
                $resultSize++;
              }
          }
      }

      return $result;
  }

  print_r(getPages(0));

?>
```

Comment: That's the exact thing I don't want to do...
I want it in a single query, not done by a for/foreach

Comment: Hum i'm sorry but there is only one query in my piece of code.

Comment: I want a single query who takes care of all the foreach stuff already.

I don't want to add subpages manually.